# Adding String functionality to class

Tags: ruby, string, delegates

Consider this class

```
class Duck
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name || 'Donald'
  end

  # Some quacking methods..

  def to_s
    "#{@name} (Duck)"
  end

end
```

I would like my duck to respond to methods like `upcase`, `sub`, `gsub`, etc.., so I can do

```
my_duck = Duck.new("Scrooge")
my_duck.upcase  
   --> "SCROOGE (DUCK)"
```

Besides manually implementing these methods, is there a nifty way I can pick out String methods that are not self-mutating and automatically have my class respond to those, then call `to_s` and then call the method on the resulting string?

Comment: `Duck#chop`, `Duck#slice`, `Duck#squeeze` :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the [`Forwardable`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/index.html) module:

```
require 'forwardable'

class Duck      
  extend Forwardable

  # This defines Duck#upcase and Duck#sub, you can
  # add as many methods as you like.
  def_delegators(:to_s, :upcase, :sub) 

  # All the other code here... 
end

Duck.new('duffy').upcase
# => DUFFY (DUCK)

Duck.new('rubber').respond_to?(:upcase)
# => true
```

In general calling `def_delegators(:foo, :bar)` is equivalent to define the `bar` method by hand like this:

```
def bar(*args, &block)
  foo.bar(*args, &block)
end
```

The first argument to `def_delegators` can be the name of an instance variable, i.e. `def_delegators(:@foo, :bar, :baz)`.

Comment: interesting, but how do you know that it is delegated to the String class?

Comment: @poseid because `to_s` returns a String.

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted. Flexible and explicit, yet concise. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `method_missing` method to check if the return value of your `to_s` implementation responds to this method and call it, if this is the case.

```
  class Duck
    attr_accessor :name

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name || 'Donald'
    end

    # Some quacking methods..

    def to_s
      "#{@name} (Duck)"
    end

    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      raise NoMethodError unless self.to_s.respond_to? m
      self.to_s.send(m, *args, &block)
    end

  end

  d = Duck.new "Donald"
  puts d.upcase    # DONALD (DUCK)
  puts d.swapcase  # dONALD (dUCK)
  puts d.downcase  # donald (duck)
  puts d.sub('D') { |m| m.downcase } # donald (Duck)
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution that certainly makes it super easy to add in all the String methods. However, I think it has a cost in readability. For instance if you do a `duck.methods`, you won't see the delegates, which means any `respond_to?` calls will fail. Furthermore, if you want to add delegation to other sources besides String and to_s, I can imagine the `method_missing` handler becoming untidy.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you would like to have something as a String Module that you could mixin into your Animal classes. However, String is a Class and the only way to access the methods from String would be inheritance on the burden of tight coupling between String and your classes.

If you need to re-use a lot of String manipulations, I would define a module:

```
module StringMixins
  def upcase
     # see e.g. Rubinius link below 
  end

  # ...
end
```

and `include StringMixins` into your target classes. That would look like:

```
class Duck
  include StringMixins

  # ...
end
```

Rubinius upcase implementation: https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/string.rb#L735-L738